# Remove weekends from timeline chart in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm analyzing the behavior at a webpage targeting enterprises and I'm trying to detect trends in the data. As expected we don't have a lot of enterprise visits on weekends and I would like to remove these datapoints in my charts to better see how the behavior changes on weekdays when we have the vast majority of all visits. Is there any way to create a filter to show only weekday data in Google Analytics?

It will not be enough to create a segment with a filter on the number of visits since if, for some reason, the number of visits would drop to "weekend-levels" on a normal weekday I need to be able to detect that.

Comment: No, I don't believe that's possible. Likely the closest you'd be able to get to what you want is changing the view from "Day" to "Week", so you only see data based on the weekly aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom report

[image: weekdys]

Then you could analyze trend in week view as @nathangiesbrecht suggested.

Comment: Ok, so it is not possible to show this in a dashboard where it's not possible to have the week view? Neither is it possible to have the day-by-day chart in any timeline, i.e. Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Mon... in a custom report? +1 for best available workaround

Comment: You're right it's impossible to show it in a dashboard. Day-by-day chart without weekends it's also impossible to create, best of my knowledge